# Insert status of SSIS package in SQL Table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msbi

My project consist of creating multiple sub directories and copy files to those sub directories. I developed this part using file system task inside a foreach loop in SSIS.

The final part is insert into SQL Table, the status of the process. If the file was copy successful the Status column should be "Successful" and the reason in another column should be "File was copied successfully" or something like that.

The error flow redirection (red arrow) is available for file system task or foreach loop? I have read somewhere that in event handlers you can work these status messages and insert them in SQL. Could someone please provide a solution or suggest one to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would steer away from using event handlers.  They are like hidden GOTOs, in which there is no indication in the control flow that they exist and you have to go to another screen to see what they are doing.

It's much more clear to use the control flow to direct errors.  Any arrow from any task or container can be double clicked and configured.  Change the constraint option to value=Failure to make the arrow go red.